# Hibernate locking MySQL with one single query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, locking

I am having a strange issue with Hibernate/MySQL, where the database is locked and blocks completely all queries. `show processlist` says following: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/aec84d0abfc3f5fcd921

It seems to me really strange that such simple query can lock the table. Especially as the transaction is as short as this native query.

I find it especially strange that it blocks ALL other queries on ALL tables.

Comment: Can you post Hibernate criteria/HQL here including opening/closing database connection.

Comment: It's just @Transactional annotation on method calling this native query. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any locked table, you would see a `Locked` state in the process list.

So that simple query runs and the locks are released when its transaction ends.

In your case I suspect you don't close the database connections when you are done with them. That would explain why the database seems blocked. The database may be fine, but the connections are already allocated, so you cannot acquire new ones.

Comment: Well, as I am using @Transactional annotation, I never actually work with the connections so I don't see how the connections can not be released? Is there a way to check what is wrong?

Comment: You can set up [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) to monitor your connection pool behaviour.